# Text moving with transform grow

Tags: html, css

I have two thing I am trying to solve.

1. The moving text, when `hover` on link.
2. (Smaller) The `span` elements are not equal (Or the circle quarter isn't, but that shouldn't be possible, since `width` and `height` match.)

It is possible to solve the first problem by giving the link `position: absolute`, but that is **not** an option. The component is used within a flexbox, which the `absolute` will kill.

```css
body{
            margin: 0;
        }
p{
  position: relative;
}
a{
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
            display:block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            /* position: absolute; */
            font: 18px Monaco, MonoSpace;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        a:hover{
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }

        a#top-left-circle{
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
            background: #006699;
            border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 0;
            border: 2px dashed #fff;
            box-shadow: -1px -1px 3px 5px rgba(0, 102, 153, 0.7), 2px 2px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);


        }
        span {
            font: 14px Monaco, MonoSpace;
            line-height: 150px;
            height: inherit;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            transform-origin: top center;
        }
.char1 { transform: rotate(-15deg); }
        .char2 { transform: rotate(-30deg); }
        .char3 { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
        .char4 { transform: rotate(-60deg); }
        .char5 { transform: rotate(-75deg); }
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#skills" id="top-left-circle" class="panel" aria-label="Hello">
        <span class="char1" aria-hidden="true">H</span>
        <span class="char2" aria-hidden="true">H</span>
        <span class="char3" aria-hidden="true">H</span>
        <span class="char4" aria-hidden="true">H</span>
        <span class="char5" aria-hidden="true">H</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple**: add to your `a` element

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

in order to tell him:

> *"hey bro, prepare to get enhancendly transformed!"*

so when you **transform** it on `:hover` - it'll respond you

> *"I knew it hahaaaaa!"*

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fakoja/edit?html,css,js,output)***

[Here's a demo on how to radially rotate characters in a circle](http://jsbin.com/xiquxa/4/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Awesome, any idea about the gap? (#2)

Comment: @PrivatMamtora ... sorry, what *gap*?

Comment: If you look at the leftmost H and the rightmost H you can see that the leftmost H has a larger gap from the edge, either I would like to know if it can be fixed or if it is expected behavior (well expected non-expected behavior)

Comment: @PrivatMamtora that gap is caused by your miscalculation of centering/rotating things. You forgot the width of the letter H > visible in this example: http://jsbin.com/fakoja/2/edit?html,css,js,output - by only increasing the line-height the right H will logically end up being that closer to the circle's edge.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora I don't know if you understand, but you set all the spans to left: 0. It should be left 0 and minus-half-the-H-width.

Comment: I made some changes to make it as close as possible: [link](http://jsbin.com/wuyorejuze/edit?html,css,js,output). Problem is it is not half but -4.5. Is there a way to do this so that it is less messy (I had to figure out `line-height` and `left` manually, bad)

Comment: @PrivatMamtora you need a relative element to be the rotatable "Stick", put at the bottom of it a 30px width absolute element to hold the centered Character, to center the element use margin-15px, than to center it's character use logically `text-align:center;` http://jsbin.com/xiquxa/1/edit?html,css,js,output (remove width 1px from the demo, I used it just for preview) - Than rotate your sticks and you're done, you have perfectly rotated sticks and centered perpendicular characters.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora see this Hello World example: http://jsbin.com/xiquxa/2/edit?html,css,js,output now let's rotate the sticks right? :)

Comment: Yeah I am streaming it

Comment: now you'll see that every letter moved and it's at the exact place as it should be http://jsbin.com/xiquxa/4/edit?html,css,js,output The only *issue now* is that we actually **monospaced** our characters, you need to custom set a different rotation angle to improve the **kerning**. For example the character L is narrower and it's rotation should be closer to the previous character, and it's next character should be closer to it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning

Comment: Ok, for now along with `monospace`, I will `all-caps` everything. (I see the kerning issue with lowercase `l`) Thanks